# Copying a nested if function

Tags: excel, if-statement, nested

I've created a nested if function that works in one cell, but when I drag it down into different cells in the same column, it starts generating weird results that I don't want.

> =IF(F2=4,G515,IF(F2=5,G514,IF(F2=6,G514,IF(F2=7,G513,IF(F2=8,G513,IF(F2=9,G512,IF(F2=10,G512,IF(F2=11,G511,IF(F2=12,G511,IF(F2=13,G510,IF(F2=14,G510,IF(F2=15,G509,IF(F2=16,G509,IF(F2=17,G508,IF(F2=18,G508,IF(F2=19,G507,IF(F2=20,G507,IF(F2=21,G506,IF(F2=22,G505,IF(F2=23,G505,IF(F2=24,G504,IF(F2=25,G504,IF(F2=26,G503,IF(27,G502,IF(F2=28,G502,IF(F2=29,G501,IF(F2=30,G501,IF(F2=31,G500,IF(F2=32,G499,IF(F2=33,G499,IF(F2=34,G498,IF(F2=35,G498,IF(F2=36,G497)))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))

It's just that, where I want it to be the same but for F3, F4, F5 etc.

Any help?

Comment: What do you mean by "weird results"?  Can you be more specific?

Comment: Cripes! Please, please, learn about Excel's LOOKUP function. It will make this code much simpler, more maintainable, and overall less terrible.

Comment: Nesting more than seven IF() statements should never have been implemented as a feature. This is a good example why.

Answer (score 1):

Try fixing you formula references by using a dollar sign $

[This article can help](http://www.notjustnumbers.co.uk/2011/05/excel-tip-dollar-sign-in-formula-fixing.html?m=1)

Answer (score 1):

When you drag something X cells down or across, all the references in your formula will be shifted X numbers down or across. To prevent this, prefix the element of the reference that you do not want changed with a `$`. For example:

- `F2`: Will change the row and column of the reference when formula is moved.
- `$F2`: Will only change the row when the formula is moved. The column will always stay `F`.
- `F$2`: Will only change the column when the formula is moved. The row will always stay `2`.
- `$F$2`: Will always stay `F2`, no matter where the formula is moved

Answer (score 0):

Even if you replace the `G`s with `G$`s the formula may still give unexpected results because `...IF(27,G502,IF(F2=28...` is incorrect syntax.

=IF(F2=4,G$515,IF(OR(F2=5,F2=6),G$514,IF(OR(F2=7,F2=8),G$513,IF(F2=9,G$512,IF(OR(F2=10,F2=11),G$511,IF(OR(F2=12,F2=13),G$510,IF(F2=14,G$510,IF(OR(F2=15,F2=16),G$509,IF(OR(F2=17,F2=18),G$508,IF(OR(F2=19,F2=20),G$507,IF(F2=21,G$506,IF(OR(F2=22,F2=23),G$505,IF(OR(F2=24,F2=25),G$504,IF(F2=26,G$503,IF(OR(F2=27,F2=28),G$502,IF(OR(F2=29,F2=30),G$501,IF(F2=31,G$500,IF(OR(F2=32,F2=33),G$499,IF(OR(F2=34,F2=35),G$498,IF(F2=36,G$497))))))))))))))))))))

is an amended version with correct syntax and dollar signs but still slightly shorter than your version, through use of OR, and should copy down as intended.

If you can be sure that only integer values between `3` and `37` will ever populate F2 etc then one of the IF statements is redundant.

If you could create an array similar to this (where the ‘G’ numbers represent the values in the cells):

[image: SO20872551 example]

a rather shorter formula should be adequate:

```
=IF(ISEVEN(F2),VLOOKUP(F2,$F$497:$G$515,2,0),VLOOKUP(F2,$E$497:$G$515,3,0))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using Choose formula and make range named.hope it helps